# Spider not recursively calling itself after setting callback

Tags: scrapy

The goal of my project is to search a website for a company phone number.

I'm attempting to parse a webpage and regex for a phone number (I have that part working) and then look for links on the page. These links are what I want to recursively call. So I would call the function on those links and repeat. **However,** it is only running the function once. See code below:

```
def parse(self, response):
    # The main method of the spider. It scrapes the URL(s) specified in the
    # 'start_url' argument above. The content of the scraped URL is passed on
    # as the 'response' object.

    hxs = HtmlXPathSelector(response)

    #print(phone_detail)
    print('here')
    for phone_num in response.xpath('//body').re(r'\d{3}.\d{3}.\d{4}'):
        item = PhoneNumItem()
        item['label'] = "a"
        item['phone_num'] = phone_num
        yield item

    for url in hxs.xpath('//a/@href').extract():
        # This loops through all the URLs found 
        # Constructs an absolute URL by combining the responses URL with a possible relative URL:
        next_page = response.urljoin(url)
        print("Found URL: " + next_page)

        #yield response.follow(next_page, self.parse_page)
        yield scrapy.Request(next_page, callback=self.parse)
```

Please let me know what you think...to me it seems like this code should work, but it is not.

Comment: Two things I would double-check first:
1. For your starting URL, are you return'ing or yield'ing the first request you are making? If you are using the default 'start_urls' in your spider class, you can disregard this.
2. Are you absolutely certain the second half of your parse() method is finding additional links on the page to crawl? Because if it does not, your method will run only once.

Please post your entire spider class so that I can help you more. Your method looks fine to me. However, Scrapy is a framework; other settings in your spider class might be causing this issue.

Comment: We need more info, what url are you crawling? Could you post crawl log? You can do this via `scrapy crawl spider --logfile output.log` or `scrapy crawl spider 2>1 | tee output.log` commands (the later puts output to screen and file).